# Looping over data in CUDA kernel causes app to abort

Tags: c#, loops, cuda, managed-cuda

***issue:***

As I increase the amount of data that is being processed inside of loop that is inside of `CUDA` `kernel` - it causes the app to abort!

***exception:***

> ManagedCuda.CudaException: 'ErrorLaunchFailed: An exception occurred
>   on the device while executing a kernel. Common causes include
>   dereferencing an invalid device pointer and accessing out of bounds
>   shared memory.

***question:***

I would appreciate if somebody could shed a light on limitations that I am hitting with my current implementation and what exactly causes the app to crash..

Alternatively, I am attaching a full kernel code, for the sake if somebody could say how it can be re-modelled in such a way, when no exceptions are thrown. The idea is that kernel is accepting `combinations` and then performing calculations on the same set of `data` (in a loop). Therefore, loop calculations that are inside shall be sequential. The sequence in which kernel itself is executed is irrelevant. It's combinatorics problem.

Any bit of advice is welcomed.

***code (Short version, which is enough to abort the app):***

```
extern "C"
{
    __device__ __constant__ int arraySize;

    __global__ void myKernel(
        unsigned char* __restrict__  output,
        const int* __restrict__  in1,
        const int* __restrict__  in2,
        const double* __restrict__  in3,
        const unsigned char* __restrict__  in4)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < arraySize; row++)
        {
            // looping over sequential data.
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above if the `arraySize` is somewhere close to 50_000 then the app starts to abort. With the same kind of input parameters, if we override or **hardcore** the `arraySize` to 10_000 then the code finishes successfully.

***code - kernel (full version)***

```
#iclude <cuda.h> 
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <device_launch_parameters.h> 
#include <texture_fetch_functions.h> 
#include <builtin_types.h> 

#define _SIZE_T_DEFINED

#ifndef __CUDACC__
#define __CUDACC__
#endif

#ifndef __cplusplus
#define __cplusplus
#endif

texture<float2, 2> texref;

extern "C"
{
    __device__ __constant__ int width;
    __device__ __constant__ int limit;
    __device__ __constant__ int arraySize;

    __global__ void myKernel(
        unsigned char* __restrict__  output,
        const int* __restrict__  in1,
        const int* __restrict__  in2,
        const double* __restrict__  in3,
        const unsigned char* __restrict__  in4)
    {
        int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

        if (index >= limit)
            return;

        bool isTrue = false;
        int varA = in1[index];
        int varB = in2[index];

        double calculatable = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < arraySize; row++)
        {
            if (isTrue)
            {
                int idx = width * row + varA;
                if (!in4[idx])
                    continue;

                calculatable = calculatable + in3[row];
                isTrue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                int idx = width * row + varB;
                if (!in4[idx])
                    continue;

                calculatable = calculatable - in3[row];
                isTrue = true;
            }
        }

        if (calculatable >= 0) {
            output[index] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

***code - host (full version)***

```
    public static void test()
    {
        int N = 10_245_456; // size of an output

        CudaContext cntxt = new CudaContext();
        CUmodule cumodule = cntxt.LoadModule(@"kernel.ptx");
        CudaKernel myKernel = new CudaKernel("myKernel", cumodule, cntxt);

        myKernel.GridDimensions = (N + 255) / 256;
        myKernel.BlockDimensions = Math.Min(N, 256);

        // output
        byte[] out_host = new byte[N]; // i.e. bool
        var out_dev = new CudaDeviceVariable<byte>(out_host.Length);

        // input
        int[] in1_host = new int[N];
        int[] in2_host = new int[N];
        double[] in3_host = new double[50_000]; // change it to 10k and it's OK
        byte[] in4_host = new byte[10_000_000]; // i.e. bool
        var in1_dev = new CudaDeviceVariable<int>(in1_host.Length);
        var in2_dev = new CudaDeviceVariable<int>(in2_host.Length);
        var in3_dev = new CudaDeviceVariable<double>(in3_host.Length);
        var in4_dev = new CudaDeviceVariable<byte>(in4_host.Length);

        // copy input parameters
        in1_dev.CopyToDevice(in1_host);
        in2_dev.CopyToDevice(in2_host);
        in3_dev.CopyToDevice(in3_host);
        in4_dev.CopyToDevice(in4_host);

        myKernel.SetConstantVariable("width", 2);
        myKernel.SetConstantVariable("limit", N);
        myKernel.SetConstantVariable("arraySize", in3_host.Length);

        // exception is thrown here
        myKernel.Run(out_dev.DevicePointer, in1_dev.DevicePointer, in2_dev.DevicePointer,in3_dev.DevicePointer, in4_dev.DevicePointer);

        out_dev.CopyToHost(out_host);
    }
```

***analysis***

My initial assumption was that I am having memory issues, however, according to VS debugger I am hitting a little above `500mb` of data on a host environment. So I imagine that no matter how much data I copy to GPU - it shouldn't exceed `1Gb` or even maximum `11Gb`. Later on I have noticed that the crashing only is happening when the loop that is inside a kernel is having many records of data to process. It makes me to believe that I am hitting some kind of thread time-out limitations or something of that sort. Without a solid proof.

***system***

My system specs are `16Gb` of `Ram`, and `GeForce 1080 Ti 11Gb`.
Using `Cuda 9.1.`, and `managedCuda` version `8.0.22` (also tried with 9.x version from master branch)

**edit 1: 26.04.2018** Just tested the same logic, but only on `OpenCL`. The code not only finished successfully, but also performs 1.5-5x time better than the `CUDA`, depending on the input parameter sizes:

```
kernel void Test (global bool* output, global const int* in1, global const int* in2, global const double* in3, global const bool* in4, const int width, const int arraySize)
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);

    bool isTrue = false;
    int varA = in1[index];
    int varB = in2[index];

    double calculatable = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < arraySize; row++)
    {
        if (isTrue)
        {
            int idx = width * row + varA;

            if (!in4[idx]) {
                continue;
            }

            calculatable = calculatable + in3[row];
            isTrue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            int idx = width * row + varB;

            if (!in4[idx]) {
                continue;   
            }

            calculatable = calculatable - in3[row];
            isTrue = true;
        }
    }

    if (calculatable >= 0)
    {
        output[index] = true;
    }
}
```

I don't really want to start `OpenCL`/`CUDA` war here. If there is anything I should be concerned about in my original `CUDA` implementation - please let me know.

***edit: 26.04.2018***. After following suggestions from the comment section I was able to increase the amount of data processed, before an exception is thrown, by 3x. I was able to achieve that by switching to `.ptx` generated in `Release` mode, rather than `Debug` mode. This improvement could be related to the fact that in `Debug` settings we also have `Generate GPU Debug information` set to `Yes` and other unnecessary settings that could affect performance.. I will now try to search info about how timings can be increased for kernel.. I am still not reaching the results of `OpenCL`, but getting close.

For `CUDA` file generation I am using `VS2017 Community`, `CUDA 9.1` project, `v140 toolset`, build for `x64` platform, post build events disabled, configuration type: `utility`. Code generation set to: `compute_30,sm_30`. I am not sure why it's not `sm_70`, for example. I don't have other options.

Comment: You don't show how you are compiling the kernel C++ code to `kernel.ptx`, but that isn't terribly important.  I think the likely answer here is that your kernel is hitting the **WDDM TDR timeout** because (in the failing cases) it is taking longer than about 2sec to run.  Just google those words and you'll get a lot of information.  If you are using nsight VSE, you can modify the timeout duration from the IDE, see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/nsight/timeout_detection_recovery.htm).

Comment: @RobertCrovella thank you! I think you are on the right direction! I was using the `.ptx` generated by the `Debug` options. After switching to `Release` - I was able to increase the minimum amount of data proccessed by `GPU` by almost 3x. I am still not reaching these results of `OpenCL` (same exception) but getting closer for sure. I will try to dig more info on timings. I will put build details into an "edit" section in minute.

Comment: @RobertCrovella do you have any idea why I can't compile the .ptx using the `arch=compute_60,code=sm_60` architecture settings? The only option that I have is 30/30. My card is from `Pascal` generation so `compute_60, compute_61, and compute_62` should be supported options..

Comment: `compute_62` is not supported.  Your card is cc6.1.  You should just be able to manually edit the `compute_30,sm_30` settings to `compute_61,sm_61`, to match your GPU, if you wish.  The debug/release mode setting is much more important, performance-wise, as you've discovered.

Comment: Alright! After changing the target architecture feature(?) level to `61` I am getting a bit better results, though, same exception is thrown eventually when it takes longer to process the data.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have to thank you once again... I have followed your link and changed the settings accordingly (10 seconds timeout). All working good now! I will update the question in a sec and post an answer.

Comment: The WDDM timeout may be the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883187/monitor-blinks-and-program-throws-exception-when-using-alea) also.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I will verify this! I will have a bit of trouble recreating that, since I was using old GPU at a time. but I think you are right. See my answer for updated test results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to improve the `CUDA` performance over `OpenCL`. And what's more important - the code can now finish executing without exceptions. The credits go to **Robert Crovella**. *Thank You!*

Before showing the results here are some specs:

- CPU `Intel i7 8700k` 12 cores (6+6)
- GPU `GeForce 1080 Ti 11Gb`

Here are my results (library/technology):

- CPU parallel for loop: 607907 ms (default)
- GPU (`Alea`, `CUDA`): 9905 ms (x61)
- GPU (`managedCuda`, `CUDA`): 6272 ms (x97)
- GPU (`Coo`, `OpenCL`): 8277 ms (x73)

***THE solution 1:***

The solution was to increase the `WDDM TDR Delay` from default 2 seconds to 10 seconds. [As easy as that](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/nsight/timeout_detection_recovery.htm).

***The solution 2:***

I was able to squeeze out a bit more of performance by:

1. updating the `compute_30,sm_30` settings to `compute_61,sm_61` in `CUDA` project properties
2. using the `Release` settings instead of `Debug`
3. using `.cubin` file instead of `.ptx`

If anyone still wants to suggesst some ideas on how to improve the performance any further - please share them! I am opened to ideas. This question has been resolved, though!

p.s. if your display blinks in the same fashion as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883187/monitor-blinks-and-program-throws-exception-when-using-alea), then try increasing the delay as well.